# Macro to Replace a column in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have Column "B" with certain links and I want to edit the link and replace column B with those edited links. I was hoping to use VBA to do that.

The data in Column B is

http://www.econone.com/staff_view.php?e=117&s=28
http://www.econone.com/staff_view.php?e=164&s=28

I need to remove "&s=28" from the links, sometimes it says &s=100 or &s=4. It could be anything. I am using the fucntion 
`=IFERROR(REPLACE(B123,SEARCH("&s",B123),10,""),B123)`
 to remove the &s=28.

How can I use this in a Macro so it would just replace all the cell contents in Column B with the Edited link

Comment: Is `&s=whatever` always at the end of the URL strings?

Comment: Are all the links in a single cell in Column B, or is there 1 link per cell in Column B?

Answer (score 0):

If `&s=x` is always at the end of the URL strings, something like

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("&s",A1)-1)
```

should work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use mid Function:

```
=MID(B1,1,SEARCH("&s=",B1,1)-1)
```